# "First time bucket" meaning Croston's method initial values

Tags: time-series, crostons-method

I'm not sure if this belongs in the 'English' stackexchange or this one, but I thought I'd try it here.

I found this about the Croston's method:

> The system checks the first time bucket of the historical values. If
>   it finds a value (not zero), it gives Z this as its initial value. X
>   is set to 1. If it does not find a value, Z is set to 1, X to 2.

What do they mean with the 'first time bucket'? I guess it's either the first value or the first values until there's a nonzero demand.

Source: https://help.sap.com/saphelp_scm70/helpdata/en/ac/216b89337b11d398290000e8a49608/content.htm

Croston's method:
http://www.robjhyndman.com/papers/croston.pdf

Comment: Croston's method may be standard for some people here, but in any case a precise source for your statement and ideally also reference(s) on Croston's method are certainly a good idea.

Comment: You're right, I edited my post with references